# How to create a stored routine that is editable from everywhere

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I am practising creating MySQL stored routines and am having problems editing them from different areas. If I create it in HeidiSQL, the definer is saved with the IP address so can only edit them in HeidiSQL from the same IP. If I create them in phpMyAdmin, it is only editable from phyMyAdmin, not HeidiSQL.

When you bear in mind that I can edit the actual table data (create, delete, drop, etc) from anywhere (if I have added the IP address), it seems ludicrous that these limitations occur with what is essentially a simple function.

Is there any way, when creating a stored routine, I can set the definer so that it is accessible from whatever program and IP address I am using?

Answer (score 0):

You need to grant [alter routine privilege](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/privileges-provided.html#priv_alter-routine) to your users on either database or global level using the [grant statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/grant.html). This way they can edit each other's stored procs. Both heidisql and phpmyadmin provide GUIs for changing privileges.

Apparently, you did not properly set up the users' privileges, so no reason to blame mysql.

Comment: The users that I created have all privileges checked. The online database's users (Siteground) can only be changed through cPanel but they have full privileges.

Comment: Then they should be able to edit the stored procedures create by the other user. So, my guess is that you did not grant full privileges to the users.